# MySQL server not loading up on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Trying to [connect my MySQL server to my Visual Studio 2015](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html#visual-studio-connection-server-explorer) so that I can work with databases within them but I seem to be stuck here:

[image]

I don't see an option to install a MySQL server. On checking the MySQL Installer, I see this:

[image]

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installed on my machine, but still see that error.

What am I missing out on? Do I need to re-install Visual Studio? Is there an alternative for me to get this running?